# How to calculate the percentage of one column, by grouping variables, relative to another?

Tags: r

My (sample) data is structured as follows:

```
Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "John", "John", "John", "John", 
                                      "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry","Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"),
                      Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                      Condition = c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", 
                                    "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr", "Expr"),
                      Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 402, 210, 130, 520, 310, 451, 608, 582, 390, 570, 300, 200))
```

I calculate the average work completed by each `Participant` under each `Condition` using the following:

```
IndividAvgWork <- ddply(Individ, c("Participant", "Condition"), summarise,
                         Power = mean(Power))
```

I now wish to calculate the `Power` performed by each minute of `Time` in the data.frame `Individ`, as a percentage of the overall mean power in `IndividAvgWork`. This must be completed for each `Participant` under each `Condition`. Is there a quick method to do this?

An example of my anticipated output, for Bill during the Placebo condition, would be:

```
RelPower = c(120.30, 75.19, 54.14, 150.38)
```

The above was calculated by: (Sampled Power / Mean Power)*100.

As a worked example, Bill's `Power` at a `Time` of 1 under the Placebo `Condition` was 400. I then divided this by the mean power for Bill under the Placebo `Condition` which is 332.50 and stored in `IndividAvgWork`. Substituting these values in gives: (400/332.5)*100

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this using library `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Individ %>% group_by(Participant, Condition) %>% mutate(PercentPower = round(Power / (mean(Power)) * 100, 2))
```

This is what it will produce:

```
Source: local data frame [24 x 5]
Groups: Participant, Condition [6]

   Participant  Time Condition Power PercentPower
        (fctr) (dbl)    (fctr) (dbl)        (dbl)
1         Bill     1   Placebo   400       120.30
2         Bill     2   Placebo   250        75.19
3         Bill     3   Placebo   180        54.14
4         Bill     4   Placebo   500       150.38
5         Bill     1      Expr   300        64.45
6         Bill     2      Expr   450        96.67
7         Bill     3      Expr   600       128.89
8         Bill     4      Expr   512       109.99
9         John     1      Expr   300        82.76
10        John     2      Expr   500       137.93
..         ...   ...       ...   ...          ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why I have -1 next to my question?

Comment: It was down voted because your original question was not clear. After the edit, it was up voted again to negate the '-1.'